# How to treat each keyword as a prefix in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am used to FTS techs doing this for me but imagine I input `mongo fac` into Elastic Search.

I expect it to be able to find `mongo factory` or `mongodb something` equally, however, it does not.

Assume I have a single field called `title`. I have three documents with the `title`s:

- Mongo Factory
- Mongodb something
- cheese

I have a single `boolean` `should` clause with:

```
array('prefix' => array(
    'title' => 'mongo fac'
)),
```

Using default analyzers, no special configuration, `mongo factory` will be found but not `mongodb something`.

What I want is for `monogdb something` to appear in the results as well, basically for Elastic Search to tokenize the keywords; as well as searching for `mongo fac` it should also search for `mongo` and `fac`.

Except for tokenizing myself what else can I do to get elastic search to work the way I want to, perferrably using their tokenizer as a means to tokenize my keywords?

Comment: What kind of query are you executing?

Comment: @phoet How do you mean? Do you want the full code or do you mean something else?

Comment: You are not giving a lot of context information. What kind of fields do you use, what kind of analyzers are you using, what type of search are you executing against the documents. From what I know, elasticsearch will find those terms.

Comment: Hopefully that adds a bit more, let me know if it doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference to others who come across this question: I didn't find a valid solution in the end so I just wrote a function to tokenise the words myself and form separate prefix queries and it works as it should.